# How to make jqGrid Style transparent

Tags: css, jqgrid

Hu everyone. I have jqGrid and want to make header row and title row transparent for this jqGrid and all its subgrids. Make something like this 
Could you please tell me how to make header row and title row transparent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.ui-widget-content, 
.jqgrow,
.ui-row-ltr,
.ui-row-ltr:hover,
.ui-state-highlight,
.ui-state-default, 
.ui-th-column,
.ui-th-ltr,
.ui-widget-content .ui-state-default, 
.ui-widget-header .ui-state-default,
#grid,
#grid tr:hover{  
    background:none;
    border:none;
    border-color:white;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yNw3C/8396/